# forward port from one IP to another IP in a local network

Tags: linux, networking, port-forwarding

I have a server on local network with local IP `192.168.0.1` that is running POP3 server on port 995 (SSL). This server doesn't have external IP and I am not in control of it.

There's another server on local network with local IP `192.168.0.2` and external IP `123.123.123.123`. It is running Ubuntu 16.04 and I have control over it.

How do access port 995 on server `192.168.0.1` via external IP `123.123.123.123`?

UPDATE: So I tried this with `iptables` on `192.168.0.2` with no success so far:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 995 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.1:995
```

Comment: I'm confused about which direction you want the port-forwarding to face. You say you want to forward from `192.168.0.1` to `192.168.0.2` whose host also has address `123.123.123.123`, but then you say that you want to access `192.168.0.1` from `123.123.123.123`, which makes it seem like what you should do is forward from `192.168.0.2` to `192.168.0.1` - in the opposite direction. What am I missing?

Comment: @igal I need to access port 995 on machine `192.168.0.1` from external IP `123.123.123.123` that has a local IP `192.168.0.2`. It doesn't matter what is forwarded what way as long as this works. I don't have control of machine `192.168.0.1`

Comment: Gotcha. I would phrase that as saying that you want to forward from `192.168.0.2` to `192.168.0.1`.

Comment: @igal Thanks. Fixed and simplified the question.

Comment: Did you enable forwarding (i.e. `echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`)?

Comment: @igol that gives me `Permission denied` even with sudo, what is it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69752/discussion-between-igal-and-caballero).

Answer (score 1):

Set up [Local Port Forwarding](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/PortForwarding#Local_Port_Forwarding) on the machine with the external IP.

```
ssh -L 995:192.168.0.1:995 localhost
```

This should let you access the POP3 server with `123.123.123.123:995`

Comment: The machine `192.168.0.1` does not run linux and I have no control over it whatsoever, so I can't use SSH, it must be done with something like iptables on `192.168.0.2` machine

Comment: Try running ``ssh -L 995:192.168.0.1:995 localhost`` on the ``192.168.0.2`` machine.  That won't rely on anything about ``192.168.0.1``

Comment: I doesn't work - `Permission denied (publickey).`

Comment: Can you do ``ssh localhost`` or ``ssh user@localhost``?

You may need to add ``.ssh/id_rsa.pub`` into ``.ssh/authorized_keys`` on the ``192.168.0.2`` machine

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand how connecting to itself is useful in this case? I managed to establish connection, but it doesn't make sense and it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @Caballero, because this command causes `ssh` to listen on port 995 on the local machine, and forward traffic received there to port 995 on another machine which it can access, namely `192.168.0.1`.

Comment: @user4556274 Understood. But the problem here is that it needs to work as something like SOCKS proxy, because port 995 is POP3 SSL. Any ideas how to tweak it?

Comment: SSH forwarding should be entirely transparent. After running the command ``ssh -L`` command, a shell prompt will be displayed that you can ignore and the forwarding should be in place.

Comment: @MarkPerryman The problem is that this kind of forwarding does not work in this case, because it doesn't preserve SSL connection - only SOCKS proxy would work (probably)

Comment: Try the following for size then https://superuser.com/questions/332850/ssh-as-socks-proxy-through-multiple-hosts